# Session is null in App_Code/.cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, session-variables, app-code

I have scoured the first few pages of google searching for this.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Is null. I can get the session for anywhere else in my application without any issue. I have created a fresh project and in that fresh project IT WORKS. The project I am working on is of a large magnitude and im not sure how to look for the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was calling the method in my class from an asmx webservice.